# ControlTemplate doesn't work properly with ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, controltemplate

I'm new to WPF, so my code may be a little bit weird. Sorry for that.

I want to change the default MouseOver and Selected event of `ListView`. Following the online instructions, I tried to change the `ControlTemplate`, but it doesn't work well (the default event disappeared, but nothing happens when MouseOver).

Then I add a border outside the `ContentPresenter`, and let triggers change the border's background. It works, but not properly. My purpose is to display something like this.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ┌─────┐ ────TEXT─────────            │
│ │     │ ────TEXT─────────            │
│ │ IMG │                              │
│ │     │                              │
│ │     │     Mouse Here, Not Trigger  │
│ └─────┘                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘ ← Enter Here
```

If I my mouse enters the listitem at the bottom-right corner and **does not move over image or text**, the background doesn't change. If I click, it is not selected.

It's appreciated if you can tell me the right way (more WPF way) to display data rather than just fix the template problem.

`ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ListViewStyle"
... // Style for ListView
<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
<Setter.Value>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="ListViewItemBorder">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ListViewItemBorder" Value="DimGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ListViewItemBorder" Value="DimGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCollections" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource DockPanelStyle}"> // LastChildFill=False
                <Image Source="{Binding something}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView
```

Comment: Do you just want to change the default colours of what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, background and borderbrush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the default template for the `ListViewItem` into your XAML markup by for example adding a `<ListViewItem />` element to a XAML file in Blend, right-click on it and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy.

You could then simply change the values of the `SolidColorBrush` resources:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCollections" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource DockPanelStyle}">
                <Image Source="{Binding something}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding something}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```